# Rolify and getting a list of User with specific access to a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan, rolify

I have two models `Organization` and `Users` which I'm using Rolify to connect.

Users have roles and Organization is a resource.

This works great however my problem is trying to get a list of users for a particular resource.  I would like to get a list of all users which have any role on that resource (and I don't care about Class level roles like universal admins etc.)

I tried doing something like below, but it's terrible and it also still returns a list of class level admins (those with admin but not actually on any particular resource).

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify

  def users
    # this is terrible and still doesn't work right.
    User.with_role(:admin, self) + User.with_role(:press, self)
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  def organizations
    Organization.with_roles(Role.role_names, self).uniq
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this.

```
has_many :users, through: :roles, class_name: 'User', source: :users
```

This should only add those that are using the roles model (skipping those on the class). You could also try something more explicit with conditions see this issue/PR:

https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/pull/181

Comment: this works, however if `Organization.first.users` is called, it will return double entries for multiple assigned roles. `Organization.first.users.uniq` will work, however `Organization.first.users.with_role :press` will not. I really wished rolify would work the way it's described in the question. Getting specific users is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer so that this may help for others.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify

  def users
    User.joins(:roles).where(
      roles: { resource_type: 'Organization', resource_id: self.id }
    )
  end
end
```

This is to filter out the users by inner joining roles table which has role entries related to a particular Organization object.